# Linux screwed up

Tags: boot, command-line, kubuntu

I tried to shrink my partition on Ubuntu but I screwed something up and I ended up with this and for some reason, the live boot from USB does not work!

[image]

Can anyone help? Please

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What exactly were you doing? What tool?

Answer (score 0):

The most "easy" way will be the following.

- create a working live Linux USB/CD/DVD
- boot that live Linux thing and open a terminal
- list your devices with `lsblk` and look for unmounted disk drives
- mount your "faulty" root partition (for example `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/`)
- read the partition information with `blkid` and write it somewhere down for later use
- make a backup of your old fstab with `sudo cp /mnt/etc/fstab /mnt/etc/fstab.old`
- open your old fstab with `sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab` and adjust the devices listed there with your new partition information, which you've got with `blkid` (you probably have just to adjust the UUID or PARTUUID of your root device and save file)
- reboot your system without your live Linux thing and pray

**PS be careful when adjusting *fstab* file, device names may have changed when booting up a live Linux thing, double check everything, if you can, prefer a live CD/DVD over a live USB**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and I got to the fils so I downloaded  them to separate USB. Unfortunately the process you vrote did not work maybe because I cannot use the cd, although I think that was not the problem. However when I got all the files that I had saved there. I reinstalles the whole linux.